# Silverlight What's wrong with this Binding statement?

Tags: silverlight, data-binding, datagrid, service, ria

I have a collection of Employees, each item has it's own collection of ProjectResource items. 
I'm trying to databind the columns but the ProjectResource won't bind.

```
<data:DataGrid x:Name="TestGrid">
            <data:DataGrid.Columns>
            <data:DataGridTextColumn Header="First Name" 
                Binding="{Binding Person.FirstName}" />
            <data:DataGridTextColumn Header="Last Name" 
                Binding="{Binding Person.LastName}" />
            <data:DataGridTextColumn Header="Week 1" 
                Binding="{Binding ProjectResource[0].PercentRequired}" />
            </data:DataGrid.Columns>
            <data:DataGridTextColumn Header="Week 2" 
                Binding="{Binding ProjectResource[1].PercentRequired}" />
            </data:DataGrid.Columns>            
  </data:DataGrid>
```

From the above you can see we get the Name details from Employee.Person and we have the subcollection as Employee.ProjectResource.
This is what I have. It makes sense(to me anyway) logically it should work but it doesn't. It displays the first and last name but no projectresource data.
Perhaps it's just a syntax error or something simple(I hope) but any help would be appreciated.

Thanks for reading

Comment: The debugger should output messages when binding is incorrect. What do your classes and binding look like?

Comment: There aren't any error messages just no data in the projectresource bound columns. They're separate entities pulled from RIA services. I tried assigning the item source after all the RIA data's loaded (so I know the data's actually there)but I still get nothing but names

Comment: what is the type for ProjectResource? is the ProjectResource initialized in the constructor? What version of Silverlight?

Comment: It's Silverlight 3. I'm not sure what you mean, ProjectResource is a table in the database it's linked to employee and project tables.  Each employee can be allocated as a project resource for each week of a project, so in the example above the project has 2 weeks with 2 entries in the ProjectResource table per employee. All these tables are present in the EF model and are loaded into the app via RIA services. The datacontext.Employees is then assigned as the itemsource for the datagrid.

Comment: Silverlight can only look at CLR objects - what is the CLR Type of ProjectResource? It must derive from IList<T> to work with the property path indexing.

Comment: Where would I find that information? I've looked at the Silverlight RIA generated code and it's an entitycollection in a class derived from DomainContext.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a fix for this though it's somewhat of a hack.

I created a newEmployee and Resource class within the silverlight app. I created a Collection and added the Employee entity items to the new collection and specified this new collection as the items source for the grid. After a few slight syntax mods to the xaml it is now fully functional and 2-way databound to the new collection.

I just have to export any changes back to the entity collection before initiating the submitchanges method.